# How can i return two javascript values to two different HTML text fields

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

So what i want to get done is that the user selects two dates from two inputs an the javascript calculates the days and print that to another textfields. Now that part is working but i also want to use the $_POST['pris'] to calculate the total price based on the number of days and print the new price to another textfield

here is the form i'm trying to both get data from and post data to with the Javascript above:

```
   function leibil(){ 

$reg = $_POST['reg'];
$bruker = $_POST['bruker'];
$pris = $_POST['pris'];

    echo" <center><h3>Fyll ut utleieskjema  </h3></center><hr/>
    <form method='POST' action='registrerbilutleie.php'>
  Lei fra:<br/>
  <input type='date' class='textbox' id='leifra' name='leifra' required onchange='cal()'><br/>
  Lei til:<br/>
  <input type='date' class='textbox' id='leitil' name='leitil' required onchange='cal()'><br/>
  Leveringssted:<br/>
    <select name='levsted'>
    <option value='Alle'>Alle</option>
    <option value='Oslo'>Oslo</option>
    <option value='Bergen'>Bergen</option>
    <option value='Drammen'>Drammen</option>
    <option value='Trondheim'>Trondheim</option>
    <option value='Lillehammer'>Lillehammer</option>
    </select><br/>
  RegNr:<br/>
    <input type='text' name='reg' value='$reg'><br/>  
  BrukerID:<br/>
    <input type='text' name='bruker' value='$bruker'><br/>
  Dager:<br/>
    <input type='text' class='textbox' name='dager' id='antalldager' disabled='disabled'><br/>
  Total Pris:<br/>
  <input type='hidden' name='pris' id='oldpris' value='$pris'>
    <input type='text' class='textbox' name='totpris' id='totpris'><br/>
  <input type='submit'>
</form>";
}
```

Here is the php file i'm have the function for the form in:

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once ("hjelpefunksjoner.php");
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Søkeresultat| Oppgave - Database & web </title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Dager(){
                var fra = new Date(document.getElementById("leifra").value);
                var til = new Date(document.getElementById("leitil").value);
                return parseInt((til - fra) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
        };

        function cal(){
        if(document.getElementById("leifra")){
            document.getElementById("antalldager").value=Dager();
        }  
    };
    function pris(){
    var dager = Number(document.getElementById("antalldager").value);
    var pris = Number(document.getElementById("oldpris").value);
    var nypris = (antalldager * pris); 
     document.getElementById('totpris').value = nypris;
      return nypris;
    };

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="top">Prosjektoppgave - Database og Web  Vår 2015</div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Hjem</a></li>
            <li><a href="members.html">Medlemmer</a></li>
            <li><a href="beskrivelse.html">Beskrivelse</a></li>
            <li><a href="sqlscript.html">SQL-Script</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="hoved">
                            <?php
                            echo"<h1>Du har valgt: " . $_POST['makeAndModel'] . "</h1>";
                            status();
                            ?>      
<hr/>

                <div id="leibilboks">

                <?php
                leibil();
                ?>
                </div>

            <div id="valgtbil">
            <?php
            VisLeieBil();
            ?>


            </div>


</div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So which part is not working? Btw you should enclosed those php scripts with <?php ?>.

Comment: I can't get it to calculate the new prise based on Days * Price

Comment: Do you want to return `(antalldager * pris)`?  This line `var nypris = (antalldager * pris);` does nothing because you are returning a DOM element (that you didn't do anything to) beforehand. Also I'm quite sure there is not an `Int` object, use `Number` instead.

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do. but i am stuck ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a problem here:

```
function pris(){
    var dager = new Int(document.getElementById("antalldager").value);
    var pris = new Int(document.getElementById("oldpris").value)
    return document.getElementById('totpris');
    var nypris = (antalldager * pris);
};
```

First note that other than `Int` you want to use `Number`, or you can do `parseInt()` on them. Also note you can drop the `new`, which I would recommend doing ( having `new` makes it a wrapper object which is probably not what you want ). Next you will want to return the value of `nypris` and it appears you want to have that value be the new value for your `totpris` element. So I'll show you how to do both:

```
function pris(){
    // Change from 'Int' to 'Number'
    var dager = Number(document.getElementById("antalldager").value);
    var pris = Number(document.getElementById("oldpris").value);

    // Calculate the value first
    var nypris = (antalldager * pris);       

    // Set the value to the element 
    document.getElementById('totpris').value = nypris;

    // return the value
    return nypris;
};
```

Comment: Are the values of `dager` and `pris` correct? Try doing a `console.log()` on them and check the console for any errors. Also is the function running?

Comment: I will add the entire files and you can see

Comment: The question is now edited.. Dager gets it values from the javascript function Dager. Pris get it value from a $_POST variable on the previous page